# Find the synchronous response to the mass-spring oscillator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
[image]

The book says the resonance happens clearly at around $\Omega \approx. 5$, but I'm not quite seeing it just by looking at the graph.

Comment: What is $A$ and $B$ in this context?

Comment: $A$ clearly reaches a maximum at $\Omega=5$, and $B=0$. I can't say more without knowing what these functions represent. Please provide more context to the problem.

Comment: I've now provided the context. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug in your solutions for A and B into the solution form you stated:

$$y(t)=A \cos  \Omega t+B\sin \Omega t$$

You can use [www.desmos.com](http://www.desmos.com).  Put a slider on the $\Omega$ value. You'll see the amplitude maximizes around 4.94 a little less than 5.